# Wear OS Complication Configuration Activity Not working

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, wearables, android-wear-complication

I was following.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/complications#2

But when I attempt to apply it to the example watch face that android studio gives  I can not seem to get passed part 3.
The gear icon under the watch face when you can change complication does not seem to want to appear.
I think it it might be related to the XML file and this line of code

`<action android:name="com.example.android.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_COMPLICATION"/>`
I have tried changing com.example.android.wearable.watchface to many different combination
related to my app nothing have been successful.

this is my Repo
https://github.com/Rob3k3/tryingcomplication

ANY HELP WILL BE MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain it's this, but your service doesn't specify that CONFIG_COMPLICATION.  There should be two matching references in your manifest.

See the codelab https://github.com/googlecodelabs/complications/blob/b3e751540fe79748e70f7a50cd2feb4482c61b20/complete/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L61

Comment: OMG!!! thank you, idk why they did not put that in the instructions. If no reason why the metadata would matter that much. BUT THANks!!!! been on this for a week!!!!